# silverstripe PHP facebook

Tags: php, facebook, silverstripe

I would like to implement a Facebook logic into my PHP SilverStripe site.
If a user is logged-in I would like to show some text otherwise I would like to show the FB login button. How should I do this?

I tried something:

```
<?php

class Page extends SiteTree 
{
    public static $db = array();
    public static $has_one = array();
}
class Page_Controller extends ContentController 
{
    public static $allowed_actions = array();

    public function init() 
    {
    require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxxxx',
      'secret' => 'xxxxx',
      'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
    ));
    $session = $facebook->getSession();

}
}
```

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

There is already a facebook-connect module for Silverstripe that provides all of this sort of functionality. It provides facebook login that is integrated with the Silverstripe login.

You can find it [here](https://github.com/wilr/silverstripe-facebookconnect).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a LoginStatus() method in the controller that returns true/false.

Then in your Page.ss template you can just use a simple conditional statement:

```
<% if FbLoginStatus %>
<!-- FB Login Button-->
<% else %>
<!-- some text -->
<% end_if %>
```